# Intent. Filtrar programa que aparece na opção "abrir com"

Tags: android, android-intent

Hoje a opção de "abrir com" lista vários programas que estão instalados no celular e inclusive meu app.
Gostaria de que meu app fosse uma opção apenas para os arquivos da extensão que ele trabalha, nesse caso "*.rlc".

```
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.rlc" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity
```

Comment: Meu app abre normalmente. O problema é que meu app é listado para qualquer arquivo. Imagem por exemplo. Nao quero abrir imagem com meu app entende?

Comment: Então você quer filtrar para que abra somente rlc, certo?!

Comment: Sim, que meu app seja listado somente em arquivos com extensão rlc. Hoje ele é listado para qualquer tipo de arquivo. Não é um problema real, mas acho que fica um pouco chato para a pessoa aparecer um programa que não pode realizar a função que ele deseja entende? Por exemplo o Android oferecer meu app para um jpg.

Comment: A maneira como você fez está certa. Mas tente acrescentar isso: `<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="file" /> <data android:host="*"`

Comment: Deu certo! Agora se eu tento abrir um cbr, por exemplo, meu app não é listado. Se eu tento abrir um rlc ele aparece e tenho como deixar como aplicação default. PERFEITO! muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Veja como é definida a sintaxe do [`<data>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html?hl=pt-br):

```
<data android:scheme="string"
      android:host="string"
      android:port="string"
      android:path="string"
      android:pathPattern="string"
      android:pathPrefix="string"
      android:mimeType="string" />
```

Agora veja abaixo como eu pode ser definido na sua `activity` no `AndroidManifest.xml` para que funcione corretamente abrir em apenas uma extensão específica. Por exemplo `.rlc`:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.rlc" />
    <data android:host="*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adicione no AndroidManufest.xml o "mimeType" na sua Intent com a extensão que será suportada.

```
<intent-filter >
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
</intent-filter>
```

Mais informações podes pesquisar a [Documentação Oficial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html?hl=pt-br)

Comment: Nesse caso seria somente substituir o "application/pdf" por "application/rlc"?

Comment: Troquei o "application/pdf" por "application/rlc" e retirei o pathPattern. Agora ele não aparece para abrir nenhum tipo de arquivo.